# Define global variable within a function in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I can see two ways to define a global variable from a function in q.

1. Using `::`

```
    q){gv::10}[]  
    q)gv /- 10
```

2. Using `set`

```
    q){`gv set 20}[]  
    q)gv /- 20
```

There is a catch with set i.e. if a global variable already has a symbol assigned to it, then the value which is assigned to global variable within the function is assigned to the symbol which is assigned to global variable.

```
q)gv:`t
q){gv set 20}[]
`t
q)gv
`t
q)t
20
```

Can someone please explain me which is the better way (`set` or `::`) to define a global variable within a function and why is it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "better" really - but `set` has the advantage of assigning to a variable name which is itself a variable (as you showed in your example).

I'm confused about your confusion in the last example though......if you wanted 20 to be assigned to a global called gv then you should put a backtick in front of gv, aka `` `gv set 20; `` and conversely if you wanted 20 to be assigned to the symbol/name that gv contains then don't use the backtick, aka `gv set 20;`

Final point to note is that you can also create globals in non-root directories/namespaces using a single colon assignment

```
q){.this.that:1;}[]
q)
q).this
    | ::
that| 1
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm clear with usage of "`gv set 20" and "gv set 20". Highlighted it in the question to make sure that the answer does not go in different usage of set.